# code skips counting the length when another list appears

Tags: python

I have a text file which is a tuple with labels ('neg', 'statements......') as shown below:

```
('neg', u'Without objection , approved .')
('posi', u'In intermeeting period , markets generally calm , investors perceived events generally positive outlook .')
('neg', u'Despite Committee \u2019 tightening policy August , yields fell across coupon curve , spreads narrowed , equities rose , asset markets continued exhibit unusually low volatility .')
('uncer', u'Despite Committee \u2019 tightening policy August , yields fell across coupon curve , spreads narrowed , equities rose , asset markets continued exhibit unusually low volatility .')
('neg', u'Despite Committee \u2019 tightening policy August , yields fell across coupon curve , spreads narrowed , equities rose , asset markets continued exhibit unusually low volatility .')
('uncer', u'Despite Committee \u2019 tightening policy August , yields fell across coupon curve , spreads narrowed , equities rose , asset markets continued exhibit unusually low volatility .')
('uncer', u'But forward rates falling gently time , apparently softer data more-tepid corporate outlooks caused market participants revise expected path monetary tightening .')
('uncer', u'But forward rates falling gently time , apparently softer data more-tepid corporate outlooks caused market participants revise expected path monetary tightening .')
('neg', u'But forward rates falling gently time , apparently softer data more-tepid corporate outlooks caused market participants revise expected path monetary tightening .')
('neg', u'The coupon curve also declined .')
```

I am trying to get the length of labels, that is 'posi', 'neg', or 'uncer' occurrences in the list of tuples.

when I run following code, I get

```
negative= [(i, 'neg')for i in file_path if i not in i.split('neg')[:n_instances]]
print (len(negative))
positive=[(i, 'posi') for i in file_path if i not in i.split('posi')[:n_instances]]
print (len(positive))
uncertain=[(i, 'uncer') for i in file_path if i not in i.split('uncer')[:n_instances]]
print (len(negative), len(positive),len(uncertain))


**Output:** 
576
0
0
(576, 0, 0)

**Expected:**
576
333
599
(576,333,599)
```

I am not sure why I get zeros length when I run the code? After series of debug, I found solution:

**SOLUTION:**

```
file_path=open('~/20021106.csv', 'r')
#20040921.20090318.csv #20021106.csv

positive=[]
negative=[]
uncertain=[]
for i in file_path:
    if i not in i.split('posi'):
        positive.append((i, 'posi'))
    if i not in i.split('neg'):
        negative.append((i, 'neg'))
    if i not in i.split('uncer'):
        uncertain.append((i, 'uncer'))

print len(negative), len(positive),len(uncertain)
```

Comment: whats the error ? where does it exactly happen? Is this the original text file structure or did you added the `(` and `)`

Comment: Why does it stop iterating over `file_path`, and why would it start again at the beginning?

Comment: What is `file_path` ? Is it a list of tuples or a file object ?

Comment: If `file_path` is a file object, then you read the file all the way to the end during the first loop.  There are no lines left to read in the other two loops.  Either rewind the file between loops (`file_path.seek(0)`), or read the whole file into a list and reuse that list for each loop.

Comment: file_path=open('~/posNegLabel/20040921.csv', 'r')

Comment: Never mind, I provided the solution up.